# Identifying the probability distribution of an experiment

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, solution-verification

> **Problem.**
>
> It is estimated that $8\%$ of the population is Type A. The remaining $92\%$ is then Type Not A. Randomly selected samples of $10$ persons are chosen, $1$ sample at a time. Assume that the population is so large that it may be considered infinite.
>
> a) What is the probability that $10$ persons of Type A will be found among the first $100$ selected?
>
> b) What is the expected number of persons that must be selected in order to observe $10$ persons of Type A?

I'm not sure how to approach this. I believe that *Part B* is an instance of the Negative Binomial Distribution, and thus the expected number of selections would be given by the density of the $NB$ distribution evaluated at $10$ (I could well be wrong, however).

I'm not certain about *Part A*.

> Now consider a variation. A population of size $20$ contains $2$ persons of Type A, and $18$ persons of Type Not A. Twelve persons are selected at random. What is the probability that, of those twelve persons, *at least* two are of Type A?

I believe this to be an instance of the hypergeometric distribution and, thus, the probability in question would be given by evaluating the density of the distribution at $N_1 = 2$, $N_2 = 18$, and $n = 12$, giving a probability of $~25.3\%$. Again, I'm not quite certain.

**How should this be approached?**

Answer (score 1):

a) You can use a binomial $X\sim \text{Bin}(100;0.08)$ but the question is a little bit ambiguous.
Assuming that you mean "exactly 10 persons" your probability is

$$\mathbb{P}[X=10]=\binom{100}{10}\cdot 0.08^{10}\cdot0.92^{90}\approx 10.24\%$$

b) Yes, you can use a Negative Binomial thus the requested expectation is derived with a known formula

$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=\frac{10}{0.08}=125$$

variation to a): Assuming (which is a natural assumption reading the text) that you select people without replacement yes, you can use an hypergeometric distribution thus but I do not know how you got 25.3%. It results to me

$$\frac{\binom{2}{2}\cdot\binom{18}{10}}{\binom{20}{12}}\approx 34.74\%$$

in this case "at least" is redundant because you have only 2 type A persons in your population